# prove this series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

prove that the series $(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+(a_3-a_4)+...$ converges if and only if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges.
I know a series is convergent if the sequence of its partial sums is bounded. I do not know how to apply that to this question.

Comment: What you wrote is not true. The sequence of partial sums of the sequence $(-1)^n$ is bounded but the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ diverges. By definition a series converges if the sequence of partial sums converges. Well, what is the sequence of partial sums in your series?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n$ the partial sums of the series.

Then by telescoping  $s_n=a_1-a_{n+1}$

So the series converges iff the sequence converges.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Note that the series you have is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_k - a_{k+1})$$

It's partial sum, in turn, is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - a_{k+1})$$

Consider trying a few small values for $n$, and consider the pattern that emerges. Use this to make a formula that is equivalent to the partial sum. In the context of that formula, what can you say happens to it as $n \to \infty$, both when $(a_n)$ is a divergent sequence, and when it is a convergent sequence?

(We approach this issue this way because we say $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges only if the sequence of partial sums - $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$, for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ - converges. Your definition of convergence for infinite sums isn't quite correct.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know of any textbook or resources so that I can study about this question in detail. I believe I know your note. but I can not see how to prove the sequence of partial sums is convergent if and only if the {a_n} sequence is convergent.